# problem with compiling a react app for the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in react js, I have a problem with compiling a react app, can someone show me the problem, please

[image]

index.js:

```
import React from 'React'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Myinfo from 'Myinfo.js';

ReactDOM.render(<Myinfo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Myinfo:

```
import React from "react";

function Myinfo() {
    return (
       <div >
        <p>jjlkjkkkjkkj</p>
        <p>jjlkjkkkjkkj</p>
        <p>jjlkjkkkjkkj</p>
        <p>jjlkjkkkjkkj</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
export default Myinfo;
```

Here is the file structure of the project.

```
C:
-react js:
  -reactjs:
       -src:
           -Myinfo.js
           -index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Myinfo.js is in the same directory as your react app then try this

```
import Myinfo from './Myinfo.js';
```